# How can I allow a single address to access multiple URL in Squid?

Tags: centos, proxy, squid

We have squid setup and it is blocking everything and allowing some specific sites for all users.
Now we have 1 user who wants to access skype and hotmail.

If we add skype and hotmail to allow_sites.txt than all users will be getting that access,  which we do not want. We want that user to follow allow_sites.txt and than 1 more acl which will give ONLY him that required access. any help is appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `acl aclname src ip-address/mask` to select only this specific user by his IP.